# OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied while trying to install pip

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install python and pip on my PC and keep getting the OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied error message.

Copy of the error in cmd:

```
C:\Windows\system32>py -m ensurepip --upgrade
Looking in links: c:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp084hi0ee
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Check the permissions.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ensurepip\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 286, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 202, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip([*args, *_PACKAGE_NAMES], additional_paths)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ensurepip\__init__.py", line 103, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run(cmd, check=True).returncode
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\python.exe', '-W', 'ignore::DeprecationWarning', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'C:\\\\Users\\\\Filip\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmp084hi0ee\\\\setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\Filip\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmp084hi0ee\\\\pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'C:\\\\Users\\\\Filip\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\tmp084hi0ee\', \'--upgrade\', \'--user\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Windows 10
Python 3.11.4

I tried installing several python versions and none of them worked. Python was added to the system variables path. Each time I tried installing I checked the "install pip" box, but the installer skipped this step (or encountered an error). After that failed I tried installing pip manually with both ensurepip and get-pip.py methods. The same error occurs either way. I tried all solutions I found online (admin cmd, give permissions to user, reinstalling python, older py version, using the "--user" option). I'm completely lost as to what to try next. Also, my knowledge of Windows and technical terms is limited so I would appreciate it if any answers are kept simple or explained in detail.

get-pip.py cmd output:

```
C:\TEMP>py get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-69.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 10.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading setuptools-69.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 819.3/819.3 kB 10.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 65.4/65.4 kB ? eta 0:00:00
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

More info:
I'm using Norton as security, but I'm unsure how this would affect anything. I tried disabling the antivirus and firewall briefly, but nothing seemed to change.

I also noticed that the folder
c:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgw775flw is never created even though cmd says `Looking in links: c:\Users\Filip\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgw775flw`
Could the problem be in some files simply missing? And why aren't they created in the first place?

EDIT:
I have fixed the issue by installing python 3.9.0 with the standard recommended instalation option, if any1 knows anything about this I'm still curious as to why is this happening with higher python versions.

Comment: open normal cmd(Not as admin:) and Try `py -m ensurepip --upgrade --user`

Comment: I already tried that and got the same error message

Comment: Try using [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). Just save the mentioned page as a python file (.py), then run it as a python script. Make sure you are doing it on a cmd with Administrative privileges.

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: The same error occurs even with get-pip.py. I will include the cmd output with this method in the question so you can take a look there.

Comment: Missing `install`.  should be `py -m install ensurepip --upgrade`

Comment: @toyotaSupra
The line I used was copied directly from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)  ->  `py -m ensurepip --upgrade`

Running the suggested command (`py -m install ensurepip --upgrade`) gives this cmd output: 
`C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe: No module named install`

Comment: I have fixed the issue by installing python 3.9.0 with the standard recommended instalation option, if any1 knows anything about this I'm still curious as to why is this happening with higher python versions.